# Promises are not working in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, q

I am new to `React.js`. In `componentDidMount` function, I am calling 4 functions parallelly using `q` module. In Every Function, I am making `API`. Once I got responses from all 4 services,I want to trigger one more function. For this I have written the following logic.

```
var q=require("q");

componentDidMount: function () {
    var self=this;
    this.setState({loader:true});
    q.all([this.getSegmentInfo(),this.getSignedUrl(),this.getOverrallMyntraMetricInfo(),this.getSegmentMetricInfo()]).then(
        function(result){
            self.makeDataForMetrics();
        },function(error){
            utils.toggleMessage(true,"Sorry Services are failed.. Try Again","verror");
        }
    );
}
```

The problem was, After I got response from all services. The dependent callback is not triggering.

All Parallel functions looks like

```
getSignedUrl:function(){
  var promiseInfo1=q.defer();
  //Making service using Ajax
  return promiseInfo1.promise;      
}
```

can anyone help me, why dependent function was not triggering.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you resolving the promises? I would assume no.

Comment: What do you mean resolve, can you show with sample code.

Comment: A promise is a container for a future value. Promises either have to be resolved with that future value or rejected with an error. If you are not very familiar with promises, I suggest to have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/.

Comment: @FelixKling I am already resolving the return promises in `then` with 2 callbacks. 1 is for success case and another for error case.

Comment: `.then` does not resolve a promise. It lets you get the value *after* the promise was resolved. Why don't you post the code of the Ajax call?

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you. Very silly mistake. I am in hurry. I didn't seen properly. Thank you.

Comment: @grandhi: Please show us your full code, not only `//Making service using Ajax` pseudo code.